# Potential Energy of interaction between two dipoles

Tags: potential-energy, geometry, dipole

We know that the potential energy of interaction between two dipoles, which make an angle $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ respectively with the line joining them and an angle $\phi$ between the planes containing them is$$U=\frac{\mu_1\mu_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}(\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\phi-2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2).$$
I know this follows from the coordinate-free formula for interaction, which is
$$U=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}\left[\vec{\mu}_1\cdot\vec{\mu}_2-3\left(\vec{\mu}_1\cdot\hat{r}\right)\left(\vec{\mu}_2\cdot\hat{r}\right)\right],$$
$r$ being the distance between the dipoles and $\hat{r}$ the unit vector along this distance. However, I don't see how the latter immediately implies the former equation. Could someone help to derive the equation containing angles from the coordinate independent form?

Comment: @V Govind could you please give me the source/reference of your question?

Comment: The equation in this form containing angles was just given to me by my professor, without any explanation, from his notes. Upon asking him, he said to consult Griffiths or Atkins Physical Chemistry, both of which contain the coordinate-free formula, but not in the form with dihedral angles.

Comment: Thanks @V Govind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the $z$-axis so $\hat r = \hat z$, and define $x$ so $\vec{\mu}_{1}$ is in the $xz$-plane. Then
$$ \vec \mu_1 = \mu_1(\sin{\theta_1}, 0, \cos{\theta_1}) $$
$$ \vec \mu_2 = \mu_2(\sin{\theta_2}\cos{\phi}, \sin{\theta_2}\sin{\phi}, \cos{\theta_2}),$$
so
$$ \vec \mu_1\cdot\vec \mu_2 = \mu_1\mu_2( \sin{\theta_1}\sin{\theta_2}\cos{\phi} +
\cos{\theta_1}\cos{\theta_2}).$$
Meanwhile,
$$ \hat r \cdot \vec \mu_i = \mu_i\cos{\theta_i}.$$
Then subtract $3\times(\hat{r} \cdot \vec{\mu}_{1})(\hat{r} \cdot \vec{\mu}_{2})$. That turns the $+1$ into a $-2$ multiplying the $\cos\theta$ products.

Comment: How did we get that cos and sin phi terms in there? It would be helpful if you could add a diagram of what we are looking at....

Comment: Not a graphic artist. But spherical coordinates: $(x, y, z) = r(\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta)$

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Here the angle between the planes is just the same as the polar angle in spherical coordinates, or, we set our coordinate system to be like that. Right?

Comment: A plane is defined by the z-axis and the dipole both being in the plane (so both orthogonal to the plane's normal). The angle between the two planes is then $\phi$ (hence, no subscript). The polar angles, $\theta_i$ are the angles between $\hat z$ and $\vec\mu_i$. Since I have made maps, I think of the z-axis as the Earth's axis, polar angle is co-latitude ($\theta \rightarrow 90^{\circ}-\varphi$), and the azimuth angle is longitude ($\phi \rightarrow \lambda$).